# SQL query returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is returning the wrong result. Please have a look at the following. I am getting the same gross salary for all employees.

I want the result like the following table:

```
S.no  Employee_name  Emoloyee_id  Gross Salary
-----------------------------------------------
1     Abc            001          1234567
2     Xyz            002          2345667
3     Dfg            003          456784
```

Here are example tables for above query. This includes following views and tables:

(a) `V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA` which includes an `Amount` column for gross salary

```
EMPLOYER_CODE  TAX_YEAR EMPLOYEE_ID  PROCESS_MONTH  PD_CODE
-----------------------------------------------------------
RAD             2014          1          1          D001
RAD             2014          1          1          Z001
RAD             2014          3          2          Z500
```

(b) `I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY`:

```
EMPLOYER_CODE  TAX_YEAR  MONTH 
------------------------------
RAD               2014    1
RAD               2014    2
```

(c) `I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER`:

```
EMPLOYER_CODE EMPLOYEE_ID   EMPLOYEE_NAME 
-----------------------------------------------
RAD                1        GODWIN  KOMBA
RAD                2        JANE  SHIBANDA
RAD                3        ANDREW JOACHIM KIIZA
RAD                4        AHMED IBRAHIM DAHAL
RAD                5        ADAM  KAWA
```

The `EMPLOYER_CODE = 'RAD'` is common for all these three tables.

Please have a look at the queries too, which are not giving the result as required:

```
SELECT 
    b.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS employeename,
    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
     FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA
     WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
       AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
                           FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL
                           WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                             AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F')
       AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 10
       AND PD_CODE = 'Z500') AS GROSS_CASUAL
FROM 
    I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A
INNER JOIN 
    I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER b ON b.EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
GROUP BY 
    A.EMPLOYER_CODE, b.EMPLOYEE_NAME
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql -server  is database

Comment: What is **S.no** in the expected result for? Where is it coming from? The presented query is not the one producing above output, is it? If "V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA which includes Amount field for Gross Salary", why don't you `SELECT E.Employee_name, E.Employee_id, P.Amount AS GrossSalary FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA P JOIN I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER E ON P.Employee_id = E.Employee_id`?

Comment: What should `GROUP BY A.EMPLOYER_CODE, b.EMPLOYEE_NAME` in the outer query address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will server your basic data that you looking for,

Change where condition as u required-

```
select 
    s.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, sum(AMOUNT)
from 
    V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA s 
inner join 
    I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER m on m.EMPLOYER_CODE = s.EMPLOYER_CODE 
                           and m.EMPLOYEE_ID = s.EMPLOYEE_ID
where 
    TAX_YEAR = 2014
group by  
    s.EMPLOYER_CODE, s.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, TAX_YEAR
```

Check your sql here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00eb0/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)` subquery counts amount for all employees, not one by one. You have `EMPLOYEE_ID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID...`. Only the employer code is filtered but all employees are processed. Therefore it is normal to get summary of all salaries. Add `V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA.EMPLOYEE_ID = b.EMPLOYEE_ID` in join/where conditions.